# AWS Lambda connects to mysql but queries timeout (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am deploying the following Lambda code using AWS CDK. It don't recall any changes in the lambda and security group configuration. But this was working a month ago. Now it is timing after connecting to the DB.

It connects to DB but then the `create database` query is not executed. And later it prints the timeout exception.

```js
const client = require("mysql2");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const fn = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const con = client.createConnection({
      host: process.env.host,
      user: process.env.user,
      password: process.env.password,
      port: 3306,
    });

    con.connect(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(
          `Could not connect to db; host -> ${process.env.host} , user -> ${process.env.user}.`
        );
        return err;
      } else {
        console.log("Connected!");

        con.query(
          `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${process.env.dbName} CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`,
          function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.error(`DB not created: ${process.env.dbName}.`);
              console.log(result);
              return err;
            }
            console.log(`Database created: ${process.env.dbName}.`);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
  return fn
    .then((e) => {
      console.log("successful");
      console.log(e);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
      throw e;
    });
};
```

Output in logs

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:16.v14 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:699b51cc1e44cad9b43e446b3b6f7e0834a78366955dc81cc7b459b0aa3f9175
START RequestId: 983e51b1-0d2f-4d6f-874b-cedf02e5c273 Version: 1
2023-06-16T07:50:04.340Z 983e51b1-0d2f-4d6f-874b-cedf02e5c273 INFO Connected!
2023-06-16T07:50:04.379Z 983e51b1-0d2f-4d6f-874b-cedf02e5c273 ERROR DB not created: 9e58a85f07a54784bc7f6542d29d9343.
2023-06-16T07:50:04.380Z 983e51b1-0d2f-4d6f-874b-cedf02e5c273 INFO undefined
2023-06-16T07:51:04.065Z 983e51b1-0d2f-4d6f-874b-cedf02e5c273 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds
END RequestId: 983e51b1-0d2f-4d6f-874b-cedf02e5c273
REPORT RequestId: 983e51b1-0d2f-4d6f-874b-cedf02e5c273 Duration: 60062.80 ms Billed Duration: 60000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 75 MB Init Duration: 268.90 ms
```

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

This was my fault. But this can actualy happen with anyone hence posting an answer to my own question. A teammate pointed this out after I posted this question here.

MySQL allows alphanumeric DB names as long as it should not start with a number. We are generating dbname programmatically and the random name we  generated here has a number in the beginning. And that caused the trouble.

Now we are prepending each generated name with an alphabetic prefix string.